# If $X_1, \ldots, X_t$ is a sequence of iid r.v.'s, what is the expected $T=t$ such that $X_t>X_1$?

Tags: probability

If $X_1, \ldots, X_t$ is a sequence of iid r.v.'s that are say, indexed by time, what is the expected $T=t$ such that $X_t>X_1$? Is it enough to know they are i.i.d or do we need a distribution on them?

Comment: Do the random variables have a discrete or continuous distribution?  The latter would be easier as in that case we will never have $X_t = X_1$.

Comment: I am assuming a continuous one. Would it entail the geometric distribution for a discrete distribution?

Comment: Does the sequence end at a fixed $t$ or does it continue indefinitely?  If it ends, what is the value of $T$ in the event that none of $X_1, \dots, X_t$ is greater than $X_T$?

Comment: I would like to assume a stream of data, so it is indefinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Here I am assuming you have an *infinite* iid sequence $X_1, X_2, \dots$ and are setting $T = \min\{t : X_t > X_1\}$.)

Let $F$ be the cdf of the $X_t$s.  Conditioning on $X_1$, the events $\{X_t > X_1\}$ are conditionally independent and have conditional probability $P(X_t > X_1 \mid X_1) = 1-F(X_1)$.  So $T$ conditionally has a geometric distribution (plus one since $t=2$ is the first possible success) with success probability $1-F(X_1)$, thus $E[T \mid X_1] = 1 + \frac{1}{1-F(X_1)}$.  This gives
$$E[T] = 1 + {E}\left[\frac{1}{1-F(X_1)}\right].$$
When $X_1$ has a continuous distribution, $F(X_1) \sim U(0,1)$ and so this yields
$$E[T] = 1 + \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-x}\,dx = \infty.$$

Comment: is there an intuition here why it is infinite? thank you

Comment: @user321627: Very crudely, if it happens that $X_1$ is particularly large then it will take a very long time to beat it.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ is a continuous rv, so that $P(X_i=X_j)=0$.

But I'll assume we are in discrete time.

Now $T>t$ iff $X_1$ is the least of $X_1,\ldots,X_t$. Each of these rvs
is equally likely to be least, so $P(T>t)=1/t$. Therefore
$P(T=t)=(t-1)^{-1}-t^{-1}=1/(t-1)t$. So the expectation of $T$ is
$$\sum_{t=2}^\infty\frac{t}{(t-1)t}=\infty.$$